# Detect horizontal overscroll and show delete option in first cell recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to show delete option with in first cell on over scroll of horizontal recyclerview like in vertical listview there is option to delete or other options on swipe item to left or right. Is there any example how can i achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link you might get the solution,
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

```
As of v22.2.0, the Android support team has included an ItemTouchHelper class that makes swipe-to-dismiss and drag-and-drop pretty simple. This may not be as full-featured as some of the libraries out there, but it comes directly from the Android team.
```

1)Update your build.gradle to import v22.2.+ of the RecyclerView library

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'`

2)Instantiate an ItemTouchHelper with an appropriate

```
SimpleCallbackItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) { 
    [...]
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
        //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
    } 
}; 
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback)
```

Note that the SimpleCallback takes in the directions that you want to enable drag-and-drop and the directions that you want to enable swiping.

3)Attach to your RecyclerViewitemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

Comment: How can i use this in horizontal recycler view?

Comment: Replace your Horizontal scrollview by this.

Comment: I tried to set LinearLayoutManager to Horizontal but its not working.

Comment: Thank you, i have managed it by using your earlier option AndroidSwipeLayout. @Mukund